# How to interpret a status other than alive or dead in data for survival analysis?

Tags: survival, dataset, interpretation

I am working on a famous data set from [this book](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Counting-Processes-Survival-Probability-Statistics/dp/0471769886). The [data set](http://www4.stat.ncsu.edu/~boos/var.select/pbc.html) consists of measurements on 418 patients. I am interested on modelling the variable;

> **futime**:    number of days between registration and the earlier of death,
>              transplantion, or study analysis time in July, 1986

in terms of some other variables. One of these variables takes three values:

> **status** :   0=alive, 1=liver transplant, 2=dead

I understand that if `status=0`, then the observed time is right-censored; if `status=2`, then the observed time is a point observation (am I correct?). However, I don't understand what `status=1` would mean in terms of the observed time. I would appreciate any pointers about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what kind of survival analysis you are doing.

A censored observation doesn't have to have only one cause (the study ended), it can have several causes (study ended, dropout, death from a cause that isn't of interest to the study [run over by a truck], etc.).  If the event of interest is death due to disease and not having received a transplant, you can call having received a transplant a censored observation.

On the other hand, you can do competing risks survival analysis instead, if that better addresses your study question.  If you think of SA as having outcomes analogous to logistic regression ({0,1} vs. {died, didn't}), then competing risks SA is analogous to multinomial logistic regression where there are >2 categories.  In this case, your categories would be {died, got a transplant, were censored}.

Comment: Many thanks for your comments. I am actually trying to fit an [AFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accelerated_failure_time_model) model, so, it is important to understand how this variable affects the interpretation of the times. I will accept your answer but it would be nice if you could make some comments in this line.

Comment: @Churchill, whether you use an accelerated failure time model or a Cox proportional hazards model doesn't matter. In either case you can use having received a transplant as censored, & in either case you can use competing risks.